# Apache Spark : TaskResultLost (result lost from block manager) Error On cluster

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark, mapreduce

I have a Spark standalone cluster with 3 slaves on Virtualbox. My code is on Java and it is working fine with my small input datasets which their inputs are around 100MB totally.

I set my virtual machines RAM to be 16GB but when I was runnig my code on big input files (about 2GB) I get this error after hours of processing in my reduce part:

```
Job aborted due to stage failure: Total size of serialized results of 4 tasks (4.3GB) is bigger than spark.driver.maxResultSize`
```

I edited the `spark-defaults.conf` and assigned a higher amount (2GB and 4GB) for `spark.driver.maxResultSize`. It didn't help and the same error showed up.

No I am trying 8GB of `spark.driver.maxResultSize` and my `spark.driver.memory` is also the same as RAM size (16GB). But I get this error:

```
TaskResultLost (result lost from block manager)
```

Any comments about this? I also include an image.

I don't know if the problem is causing by the large size of `maxResultSize` or this is something with collections of RDDs in the code. I also provide the mapper part of the code for a better understanding.

[image]

```
JavaRDD<Boolean[][][]> fragPQ = uData.map(new Function<String, Boolean[][][]>() {
        public Boolean[][][] call(String s) {
            Boolean[][][] PQArr = new Boolean[2][][];
            PQArr[0] = new Boolean[11000][];
            PQArr[1] = new Boolean[11000][];
            for (int i = 0; i < 11000; i++) {
                PQArr[0][i] = new Boolean[11000];
                PQArr[1][i] = new Boolean[11000];
                for (int j = 0; j < 11000; j++) {
                    PQArr[0][i][j] = true;
                    PQArr[1][i][j] = true;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SOLVED:

The problem solved by increasing the master RAM size. I studied my case and found out that based on my design assigning 32GB of RAM would be sufficient. Now by doing than, my program is working fine and is calculating everything correctly.

Comment: Facing similar issue (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48455547/apache-spark2-0-taskresultlost-result-lost-from-block-manager?noredirect=1#comment83908776_48455547)) did u change the driver-memory ?

Answer (score 6):

In general, this error shows that you are collecting/bringing a large amount of data onto the driver. This should never be done. You need to rethink your application logic.

Also, you don't need to modify `spark-defaults.conf` to set the property. Instead, you can specify such application-specific properties via `--conf` option in `spark-shell` or `spark-submit`, depending on how you run the job.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The driver should not do any significant work, right? WebUI shows just 2 counting tasks which takes just a few seconds and this is the reduce part which it is running on all of the workers so where and how driver getting data is unclear. There is no indication of Mapping process and when it gets done that is why the monitoring becomes so confusing.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I got this error because a firewall was blocking the block manager ports between the driver and the executors.
The port can be specified with:

- `spark.blockManager.port` and
- `spark.driver.blockManager.port`

See https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#networking